# Why changing IIS Express Project URL does not work in ASP.NET MVC 4.7.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this setup to change the URL to 5002.

[image]

After running, this the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our friends at MS support:

"IISExpress uses http.sys for its communication and it requires SSL ports to be registered as Administrator. To avoid running Visual Studio as administrator, IIS Express reserves the port range 44300 - 44399 when it is installed. As long as you select a port within this range (which is what VS does) you do not need to run IISExpressAdminCmd to register the URL."

via support link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/39430/changing-port-number-in-a-web-project-does-not-imm.html

Solution #1 Use IIsExpressAdminCmd.exe to register the URL

From cmd prompt go to directory
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express

Run IISExpressAdmiCmd to register the url
IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupsslUrl -url:https://localhost:5002/ -UseSelfSigned

Solution #2
Run VS under admin context

Solution #3
Switch the port to a pre-registered one 44300 - 44399

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try;

- Search through your project code (using find all) looking for
  instances of "5002" or whatever your port number was previously. You
  will be looking for references in generated code rather than code you
  have created yourself.
- Try with a difference browser (Chrome / Firefox etc).
- Shut down any other running applications.
- Try running without https. If this works you can focus your effort on getting the developer certificates working.
- Stop and start visual studio (its annoying how often this solves anomalies!)
- Check that the IIS express instance is running in the tray - click on the tray, locate the respective running application and
  click browse.
- Create a completely clean application using port 5002 and compare the two solutions to relevant differences.
- Reboot and try again - in case there are any other applications locking this port number.